# how to extract an object from an image

Tags: image, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I want to extract an object such as a man ,a car or something like that from an image.The image is just an ordinary iamge, not medical image or other types for specific purpose.

I have searched for a long time and found that the automatic image segmentation algorithms just segment the image into a set of regions or gives out the contour in the image,not a semantic object. so I turned to the interactive image segmentation algorithms and I found some popular algorithms like interactive graph cuts and SIOX and so on. I think these algorithms just meet my demand.

Further more, I also downloaded two interactive image segmentation tool,the first one is the [interactive segmentation tool](http://kspace.cdvp.dcu.ie/public/interactive-segmentation/index.html), the second one is the [interactive segmentation tool-box](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mohitg/segmentation.htm).

So my quesions are

1.if the interactive image segmentation algorithm is the right solution for my task since the performance is the most important.

2.and if I want to use the automatic image segmentation algorithm, what should I do next?

```
Any suggestion will be  approciated.
```

Comment: Not sure why people has votes to close the question. Looks a valid one even when the writer could have formatted it a bit.

Comment: Could you tell me where can I see the votes to close the question? I just see nothing.Thanks.

Comment: Probably you don't have permissions to see them. There are 4 links: link, edit, close and flag

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pick out a object from a single static image just by a few scribbles. I recommend you have a read of

```
'Closed-form solution to image matting' 
or 'Spectral matting', 
or 'lazy snapping'
```

but as in my tests, the last doesn't perform as well as the first two methods when dealing with subtle objects like hairs.
However you can find their source matlab codes very easily from google.

But the first two method are't so pleasant to use actually, I think you'll need to do lots of modification to make them easy to use. It's main problem IMHO, is it requires very decent scribbles on the image, that's if you draw some extra scribbles or at wrong positions, you'll ruin your object cutting .

Apart from these, you may try 'bayesian matting, possion matting, etc.' which all request some helping image called trimap, and it's hard to draw really.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting objects from an image, specially a picture is not that easy as you think, you may want to take a look at the OpenCV project.

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.As I'm a beginner on computer vision, so I surveyed a lot to find an existing solution to learn from it. If I do it from scratch, the time will not be enough.Since I find some interactive segmentation algorithm could perform my task, I'm not sure if this is the "right" solution from the standpoint of professionals and if there are a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Other than OpenCV, I would suggest looking at [ITK](http://www.itk.org/). It is very popular in medical image analysis projects, because there it is known that semi-automatic segmentation tools provide the best results. I think that the methods apply to natural images as well.

Try looking at tools like livewire segmentation, and level-set based image segmentation. ITK has several demos that allow you to play with these tools on your own images. The demo application such as [this](http://www.itk.org/ITK/applications/segmentationeditor.html) is part of the open source distribution, but it can be downloaded directly from the itk servers (look around for instructions)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this toolkit to determine which best suits my task.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a business case, you'd better look for companies specialized in "video content analysis". I mean it: reliable people and vehicle detection aren't a single man's project.

Genreral purpose segmentation tools won't do the trick because they have no notion of what a man or a car look like. All they are deemed to do is to find uniform regions in an image.

Comment: I read some theses and I got that automatic image segmentation can't solve the "semantic gap" problem, so you're right.                             And now it seems that if I want to extract an object from an image which means to bridge the gap between the low level features and human semantics I have to fall back on myself. so the interactive segmenation algorithm seems to be the most simple and direct solution now .

Answer (score 0):

It is quite late but there is an algorithm called `connected component labeling`, which you may find useful.

here is [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) of the algorithm